# What does it mean when data bus is 32 bits wide

Tags: architecture

I understand that it's referring to the Register size of the CPU. If register size is 32 bits it makes sense to have a 32 bit data bus to transfer the data.

My question is, is the bus actually deigned to handle only 32 bits at a time? isn't just a wire? can't it technically handle more bits at once?

Comment: It is very likely 32 (tiny, parallel) wires.

Comment: Bus-width divided by register-size is generally a (possibly negative) power of 2 for efficiency. Otherwise, there's not necessarily any relation.

Comment: A single track of wire can handle one bit of data (bit = binary digit).  A 32 bit bus has 32 tracks (or less, if multiplexed)

Answer (score 3):

Although they make some good points I suspect Erik's and amon's answers only add to your confusion.

When you read about a 32-bit data bus, it means you have 32 parallel wires running from the CPU to the memory interface. I am talking about the kind of memory a typical modern PC will have a couple gigabytes of. Where your programs are loaded into before they are executed and that is used as work memory for variables.

When the CPU reads either program instructions or data from memory, it sets the bits on the address bus to a number that identifies a memory location. The address bus wires also run to the memory interface. Another wire acts as a traffic regulator. Think of it as going up to tell the memory it should now fetch the  bytes pointed to by the address set on the address bus. When the traffic regulator line goes down the CPU knows the data it set on the data bus are valid and may be clocked in.

In reality it may take several ups and down of the traffic regulator to get the bits across, that is not the point. The point is that with a 32-bit data bus you will have 32 wires running from memory to CPU dedicated for data transfers and you get 32 bits from the memory to the CPU in one communication cycle.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter if a 32 bit data bus is implemented as 32 wires that each transport 1 bit per cycle, or one wire that transports 32 bits serially per cycle, or anything in between.

The important part is that there is necessarily some limit on the amount of data that can be transferred *per cycle*, whether this is 16, 32, or 64 bits. It is convenient to choose memory bus width, register size, and address size all as the same “[word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture))” size. It is of course possible to create a memory bus that can transport more than that, e.g. to load a double-word at once.

Whether this is the case depends highly on the intended use case of the instruction set.

- MIPS tries to be a minimal, orthogonal instruction set and includes no actual instructions to load doublewords directly (though an assembler might offer a pseudo-instruction for programmer convenience).
- In contrast, AMD64 (x86-64) with its various extensions is more concerned about being an efficient multi-purpose instruction set. While nominally a 64-bit instruction set, it also defines 128-bit registers and instructions like MOVDQA. However, the x86 instruction set is an absolute outlier in many ways, including its support for different addressing modes and word sizes.

Comment: "per instruction" is probably better than "per cycle"

Answer (score 0):

The consideration for modern processors is that some caches are on chip.  Thus the chip's memory bus interface is then going to be from a cache to off chip memory.  Here you would want the largest bus you can afford, maybe up to the cache line size, which might be 16 bytes!

The CPUs bus interface will be internal to the chip, and going to an internal cache.